# Two light switches, one with only two screws and four wires

Tags: electrical, switch

I’m not even finding photos of the switch I have online so I’m asking for advice.

I have two switches in the same box. The first one has only two screws: top left (TL) and top right (TR). TL is black black (BB) and TR is BB. No idea how to wire this one.

The second switch is a normal single pole. TL is W TR is B and bottom right (BR) is R. This one seems like a one for one swap with a single pole.

As far as I know they control a series of outlets of which I haven’t figured out just yet.

For some reason I could only upload one photo, but the other side is identical to this one.
I need advice, what type of switch do I need for the first one, and are the two collectively wired correctly?[image]

Answer (score 3):

You need a switch that can take aluminum wires and copper. Not all do.

That switch is just in the centre of circuit instead of being at an end. So one hot wire coming and one going somewhere else. Same with the other side.

Good quality switches can have two wires per screw under clamps, but most are only allowed one wire per screw. In those cases you use wire pigtails to join a short wire to the switch from the other two wires.

Newer code says to use torque drivers when connecting wires with screws.  This is very important to do with aluminum wires.  No torque is one reason why Al wires got a bad rap before.

There seems to be a neutral wire bundle in that box, so smart switches should be easier to install later on if you go that way.

Comment: If you need to make copper pigtails for any reason, do some research about best practices. Again, it usually involves a torque screwdriver and a listed connector ("alumiconn" for example). For better or worse, purple wire nuts have a bad reputation even though UL listed.

Comment: Thank you so much!